# Access @Inject variable in @code - .net Core Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor, razorengine

I am new to Blazor .net Core. I have injected service settings in my .razor page

```
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<Configuration> Configuration
```

Next I have `@code` directive below that initialise the _m object

```
@code 
{
    private ViewModel _m = new ViewModel(Configuration.Value);

    protected async Task DoSearchAsync()
    {
        await _m.PerformSearchAsync();
    }
}
```

Registered code in **ConfigureServices**:

```
services.Configure<Configuration>(options => 
    Configuration.GetSection("ConfigurationSettings").Bind(options));
```

**Configuration.cs**

```
public class Configuration
{
    private string ServiceEndpointUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I need to pass the Configuration to `ViewModel()` constructor that takes `IOptions<T>`, but for some reason I cannot access my injected variable "Configuration" in `@code` directive. How do I access that please?

Comment: what syntact problem?

Comment: Have you configure an option name `Configuration` in your DI ?

Comment: yes I have added that.

Comment: Can you post the registring code with namespace declaration and your *_Imports.razor*

Comment: And post your `Configuration` class. And maybe rename at the same time.

Comment: Have added the configuration file.

Comment: Part of your problem might be that just about everything is called 'Configuration`.

Comment: Its not the actual name I have used in my code, its just a dummy name.

Comment: Do not post fantasy code with dummy names. Create a [mcve] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your injected Service inside a method like:

```cs
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<Configuration> cfg

@code {
    private ViewModel _m;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        _m = new ViewModel(cfg.Value);
    }

    protected async Task DoSearchAsync()
    {
        await _m.PerformSearchAsync();
    }
}
```